# Any good reason for passing ServletResponse as parameter?

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any good reason why `javax.servlet.Servlet`'s
`void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)` method has the `ServletResponse` given as parameter, instead of just returning it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Servlet API is an abstraction and defines the minimum requirements needed by any Java Web Application to handle any kind of request (if you look at it you will notice that almost all classes there are defined as interfaces or abstract classes).

This API has been defined by the [JCP](http://jcp.org/en/home/index) after a process in which different Java Server vendors (IBM, Sun, Apache, Oracle, etc.) agreed on the minimum requirements thus defining what is considered now as the official standard. However, the different vendors have different ways of implementing their servlet containers resulting in the diverse amount of them nowadays (each of them with different features).

Since servlet containers need to keep track of both objects (the request and the response) to do a proper handling of both, they can't leverage the responsibility of creating a `ServletResponse` (or the HTTP variant `HttpServletResponse`) to the user - remember that what goes inside the Servlet's `service` method is user code. So, servlet containers create and prepopulate a request and response objects (using their own implementations) prior to invoke the `service` method. From the user point of view, just handling them through the interfaces is enough and this also protects vendor-specific code since we don't have access to the actual implementation of both objects.

However, when the API was defined these vendors realised that, in some cases, the user would like to override the default behaviour of any of those objects so they included a set of wrappers (`HttpServletRequestWrapper`, `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, etc.) that can be extended by user code and used in either servlets or filters to replace the default implementations provided by the container.

Answer (score 0):

A complete cycle of a request   consists of a `request` and a `response`,when  we make a request  A request and A response objects creates by container and give access to handle them.

If you see docs

> Called by the servlet container to allow the servlet to respond to a request.

The response object associated to the request,You have to just respond to that request.

If you create a `Response` object on your own,Without a request ,can you send a response randomly?

Answer (score 0):

The object passed in as `res` will be a container specific subclass of `ServletResponse`. You cannot create such an instance yourself in a container independent way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the request from the client the web container creates a ServletResponse Object and passes this object in the service method so that the response to the client can be provided.

Comment: the response hasn't been executed yet in the `service` method, it's just prepopulated. If it were executed then you wouldn't be able to modify any of its values, like headers or the response contents.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez: agreed and edited my answer.please updo your downvote